# Sanitizing input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, sanitize

this may be a really n00b question, but if your list of params contains a bunch of stuff that isn't an attribute accessible, ie

```
params = {"controller"=>"api1/users", "action"=>"create"}
```

what is the best way to "sanitize" your params so that they only contain the accessible attributes. The current way that I thought of currently is to do :

```
User._accessible_attributes[:default].entries
```

that gives me a list of accessible attributes and then only pass those params:

```
["", "email", "password", "fb_token", "fb_id", "fb_name", "first_name", "last_name", "gender"
```

Another possible way is to have this:

```
  def clean_params #ANTIPATTERN
    params.delete(:controller)
    params.delete(:action)
  end
```

but this also feels like an antipattern...

I know that you're supposed to do something like params[:user] to get only the accessible params, but because this is an API, it would be nice to be able to pass things just in the url.

Thanks!

Comment: Won't Rails already enforce [`attr_accessible`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible) for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rails parameter wrapper will do this for you automatically. That is, it will accept parameters at the top level and group them under, for example, `:user` for your convenience, filtering out any that are not accessible to the User model. Internally it uses `accessible_attributes`, similar to what you've done. People who use your API will not need to group attributes -- rails will do it before it hands the params to your controller action.

By default it's turned on for JSON requests, but you can expand that by editing `initializers/wrap_parameters.rb`. Or you can adjust the behavior on a per-controller basis using the [`wrap_parameters` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper/ClassMethods.html#method-i-wrap_parameters) in your controller.

The rails scheme of parameter sanitizing is likely to change in 4.0, trending away from the model and toward the controller. You may want to watch development of the [strong_parameters gem](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) which could be a preview of things to come.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way... This will only sense in the parameters you want to in the controller. credit: [dhh's gist](https://gist.github.com/1975644)

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html

  def create
    respond_with User.create(user_params)
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params[:user].slice(:email, :first_name, :last_name)
  end

end
```